# Why doesn't my JButton show?

Tags: java, jframe, jbutton, jlabel

```
public class StartMenu extends JFrame {
public static void StartMenu() {
   JFrame StartMenu = new JFrame("SamBallPool");  //New Windwow With Title

   StartMenu.add(new JLabel(new ImageIcon("Data/StartMenu.png")));  
   StartMenu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);   //Set Close Operation
   StartMenu.setSize(600, 330);
   StartMenu.setVisible(true);

   JPanel StartPanel = new JPanel();
   StartPanel.setLayout(null);  
   StartPanel.setVisible(true);
   ImageIcon Start = new ImageIcon("Data/StartButton.png");  //Play Button in Center
   JButton StartButton = new JButton(Start);  
   StartButton.setBounds(263,101,70,53);  //Positioned Button Over Image of Button

   StartButton.setVisible(true);
   StartButton.setEnabled(true);

   StartButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
   public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent StartButtonClicked){
         JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null,"Test");
         MainMenu.MainMenu();
         StartMenu.dispose();
      }
   });
   StartPanel.add(StartButton);
   StartMenu.add(StartPanel);
       }
}
```

The button does not show up, filepath is correct, even without the image it doesn't show up. It used to show up but stopped working for some reason, thanks for help in advance :(

Comment: *It used to show up* - did you change something since then? Anything?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! 
Please take the [tour](/tour), have a look around, and read through the [help center](/help), in particular [How do I ask a good question?](/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here?](/help/on-topic).
Please read (and follow) the 
[Java Naming Conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html)

Comment: I have the feeling removing `extends JFrame` from your code will expose your problem.  You don’t seem to have any need for a custom subclass of JFrame.

Answer (score 0):

You call `StartPanel.setVisible(true);` too early. It must be the *last* statement after configuration of the form is completed.

Comment: I don’t think that’s the issue.  All components other than Windows are visible when created, so that setVisible(true) does nothing.

Comment: Everything shows up if i resize the frame and hover over the button with the mouse?

Comment: Adding StartMenu.pack() and StartMenu.validate() kinda solves the problem, however i still have to hover the mouse over to show the button?